# Code in AsyncTask not executing in Java

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

In order to allow read/write operations to occur to a text file, I have needed to place the operations in an AsyncTask. However, since i have set the AsyncTask up i have not been able to get it to execute.

Since i am doing all the operations in the AsyncTask, i have not put anything in the post execute.

**Code of AsyncTask:**

```
public class SaveTopic extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        File file = getContext().getFileStreamPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/topics.json");

        if(!file.exists()){ //Checks if file exists (creates if not)
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

            try{
                //true = append file
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true); //true = append file
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            bufferedWriter.write(flat);
            bufferedWriter.close();

            }catch (IOException e){
            //TODO message that error in file handling  

            }


            try{
                FileReader fr = new FileReader("topics.json");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

                String str;
                while((str = br.readLine()) !=null){
                    Log.e("log_tager", str + "\n");
                }

                br.close();

            }catch (IOException e){


            }

            return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String outstring){

}
}
```

**Notes:**

- I have made sure that the AsyncTask is within the main class.
- new SaveTopic().execute(); has been added.
- "flat" is a public string.

**Edit:** The error i am receiving is due to the file name:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(6886): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /storage/emulated/0/topics.json contains a path separator
```

Comment: You need to either pass a string with execute or change the input param to void.

Comment: I have changed the code in the question to what I thought you meant but I think I misunderstood you somewhat.

Comment: Add "Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getStackTrace().toString());" You need to log your exception for more information. You are most likely getting an error within your try/catch blocks and they're to showing up since you are not logging and the async moves on since it returns void. Thus you will not see anything.

Comment: Change the third param of the async task to string

Comment: That isn't going to solve your problem, since you are not passing in any values or returning any as well. You are fine the way you have it set up, even though I would do it differently. I bet there is an error within your try catch which stops the whole AsyncTask and that's why you aren't seeing results. If an AsyncTask stops, your application doesn't stop since it returns void, and that is why I am recommending the to log the catch blocks within your try/catches.

Comment: in postExecute you are sending result as string while you are extending from AsyncTask <Void,Void , Void> .. Result must be string .. as Asyn parameter

Comment: @RedRumming You are correct, both of my try attempts do not execute. Could you offer an explanation?

Comment: Add `e.printStackTrace();` in both of the `catch` blocks in `doInBackground`. You are getting exceptions there

Comment: @Apoorv The log has shown me W/System.err(5999): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /topics.json: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system) I read somewhere that the data/ section in android is only accessible to rooted devices. Is this a case of changing where i store the file?

Comment: It needs the whole path to the file and not just the file name.

Comment: Ok, i have added changed code to

File file = getContext().getFileStreamPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/topics.json");

I am receiving the error: 
E/AndroidRuntime(6886): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /storage/emulated/0/topics.json contains a path separator


Edited question is that helps.

Comment: I think you have to remove or replace the forward slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method opens a file in the private data area of the application. You cannot open any files in subdirectories in this area or from entirely other areas using this method. So use a `FileInputStream` or such

file.exists is. But getFileStreamPath can't take a path, it needs to take a filename in that directory. Try this:

```
File file = new File(this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/topics.json");
```

Comment: Thanks. It was this combined with file.getName() it worked when i got rid of the .getName and changed it just to file.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code there is nothing that you wanna update on UI then why use `AsyncTak`. A simple `Thread` should suffice.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
     // Your code here
    }
  }
thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this. Since it looks like you have hard coded some String values when they can be a variable and make things simpler. Also the FileReader can take in a file instead of a String which would be a lot easier and simpler to read in my opinion.

I believe Aproov is correct when it comes to the FileReader that you give then name but it needs the whole name such as the folder that the file is in. I also believe Nepster is correct that there was an extra slash but I am not 100% sure.

I hope this helps or at least points you in the right direction to help solve your problem.

```
public class SaveTopic extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            //Filename 
            String fileName = "topics.json";          

            File file = getContext().getFileStreamPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" +fileName);  //Filename variable instead of hard coded string

            //Checks if file exists (creates if not)
            if(!file.exists()){ 

                try {

                    file.createNewFile();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                     Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), e.printStackTrace());
                }
            }


            try{


                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);//Pass the file object
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
                bufferedWriter.write(flat);
                bufferedWriter.close();

            }catch (IOException e){

                Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), e.printStackTrace());
            }


            try{
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(file); //Lets pass the file into the constructor instead of a hardcoded string. 
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

                String str;
                while((str = br.readLine()) !=null){
                        Log.i("log_tager", str + "\n");
                }

                br.close();

           }catch (IOException e){

                Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), e.printStackTrace());

           }

           return null;

    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String outstring){

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I found that the slash needed to stay there or it would conjoin the file name and directory together. Would your code above allow for file.getName() since on removing the .getName() part, the error had gone.

Comment: I would remove the file.getName() and just use file. Keep it simple and just use the file object as the reference since FileWriter(File file) is one of the possible constructors. It would make more sense to just pass one file around instead of the file and the file name.